# Why is my Django template not loading?

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

I have the following code which seeks to pull a number **"counter"** out of a DB, add a value **("+1")** to it, save the new **"counter"** value, wait for a specified amount of time, and then start again from the beginning. This same function would be called via a view on Django, so it is also responsible for generating the template as well.

According to the development server, the function IS performing the simple arithmetic and saving the new value to the DB. As I can see the value being updated every time I refresh the Django-Admin.

However, it fails to load the template. Specifically, the page stays loading indefinitely, while the calculations happen.

Sorry if the code isn't perfect, I'm new to everything ever.
Also, please note that I have previously tested the entire ecosystem with a much simpler index function (generates simple HTML) and the template indeed generates. So I'm assuming that the problem must come from this code specifically.

## Views.py:

```
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   from django.template import Context, loader
   from home.models import DeathNum
   import datetime
   import time

   def index(request):
       while True:
           counter = DeathNum.objects.get(pk=1)
           counter.deaths += 1
           counter.save()
           print('Added @ %s ' % datetime.datetime.utcnow())
           time.sleep(35)
       return render(request,
                     'home/basenum.html',
                     {'number_post': str(counter)}
                     )
```

## basenum.html (extending template):

```
     {% extends "home/index.html" %}
        {% block content %}
        <br />
         <div class="banner">
          <div class="bannerNum">
      <p div class="numberOf">
          Number of deaths in Blank since 1999:
      </p>
        <br /><br /><br />
      <p class="death1">
         {{ number_post }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop while True.

Answer (score -1):

you have to change two things in view function and queryset.

```html
def index(request,pk):
 counter = DeathNum.objects.get(pk=pk)
 """your logic here""
 return render(request, 'home/basenum.html, {'number_post': str(counter)})
```

make sure your urlconf should be correct